SAML authentication getting failed sometimes with Credential Expired Exception
We are using Spring Security SAML Extension Project. But we are experiencing some weird issue with the users as stated below,
We have set the maxAuthenticationAge to 8 hours in the WebSSOProfileConsumer bean like below,
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
    CustomWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl consumerImpl = new CustomWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    consumerImpl.setMaxAuthenticationAge(28800);
    return consumerImpl;
}

But sometimes when the users are trying to login they are facing 404 error and the authentication is getting failed and they are redirected to rest/saml/sso.
Below is the SAMLResponse and Exception we get in the logs.
SAMLResponse:
2024-11-19 07:16:39.718  INFO 122 --- [http-nio-80-exec-72] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNResponse;FAILURE;<user ip address>;example.com;https://sts.windows.net/5dbf1add-202a-4b8d-815b/;anonymousUser;<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://example.com/rest/saml/sso" ID="_9e3eada3-8ef9-4931-8f22-829d9f3652a3" IssueInstant="2024-11-19T07:16:39.576Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.windows.net/5dbf1add-202a-4b8d-815b/</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status><Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_c35b2a21-e2d1-4b9e-b005-3a5d5bed1300" IssueInstant="2024-11-19T07:16:39.573Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/5dbf1add-202a-4b8d-815b/</Issuer><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI="#_c35b2a21-e2d1-4b9e-b005-3a5d5bed1300"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>/Rshctyx1KcPNvuPfdgfdgsdgsdA0+QHXecyNy9DKjlB7HXUtM6/yY=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>AxLs80XLFEgJ307yLGdfgdsgdsgsdgdsgsgSl1M1OwQOdNw==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIIC6DCCAdCgAwIBAgIIMkG9mK3/5a0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwNDEyMDAGA1UEAwwpTWljcm9zb2Z0IEF6dXJlIEZlZGVyYXRlZCBTU08gQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwHhcNMjQwODEyMDQyNzAyWhcNMjcwODEyMDQzNzAxWjA0MTIwMAYDVQQDDClNaWsdrfewgtregdfbdzfbdfzbNyb3NvZnQgQXpasfsdg1cmUgRmVkZXJhdGVkIFNTTyBDZXJ0aWZpY2emxWrw==</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature><Subject><NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">123456</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-11-19T08:16:39.317Z" Recipient="https://example.com/rest/v1/saml/sso"/></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2024-11-19T07:11:39.317Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-11-19T08:16:39.317Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>example.com</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid"><AttributeValue>5dbf1add-202a-4b8d-815b-bf0fb024e033</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"><AttributeValue>677d-4f61-4c05-a283d-acb488</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname"><AttributeValue>Hi Hello</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider"><AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/5dbf1add-202a-4b8d-815b/</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences"><AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/x509</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/multipleauthn</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"><AttributeValue>Hello</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname"><AttributeValue>Hi</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"><AttributeValue>hello@example.com</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"><AttributeValue>hello@example.com</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gid"><AttributeValue>123456</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-10-16T07:45:37.771Z" SessionIndex="_c35b2a21-e2d1-4b9e-b005-3a5d5bed1300"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion></samlp:Response>;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.microsoft.azure.appservice.filters.AppServiceFilter.doFilter(AppServiceFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.microsoft.azure.appservice.EasyAuthFilter.doFilter(EasyAuthFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException: Authentication statement is too old to be used with value 2024-10-16T07:45:37.771Z
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAuthenticationStatement(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:538)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:308)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
... 97 more

Timestamp printed in the logs against the credential expired exception is something old one and not the recent logged in time by the user.
Note - Above issue is not happening for all the users and it is occurring only to some users.
I have two questions here.

Why the old timestamp is fetched here for authentication?
How can we debug or backtrack the credential being sent for SAML authentication?

Kindly please help, Thanks in advance.
